# Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer path problem

Tags: php, excel

I have tried the following program for writing the contents into Spreadsheet.
I downloaded the Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer package also.

```
<?php
ini_set('include_path','/xhome/rekha/public_html/PHP_FORUM/PHP/open_office/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.2/Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php');

$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
$workbook->send('grades.xls');
$format_bold =& $workbook->addFormat();

$format_bold->setBold();

$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet();

$worksheet->write(0, 0, "NAME", $format_bold);
$worksheet->write(0, 1, "MARK1", $format_bold);
$worksheet->write(0, 2, "MARK2", $format_bold);
$worksheet->write(0, 3, "MARK3", $format_bold);
$worksheet->write(0, 4, "MARK4", $format_bold);
$worksheet->write(0, 5, "MARK5", $format_bold);
$worksheet->write(0, 6, "TOTAL", $format_bold);

$workbook->close();
?>
```

But while running this php program I got the following Fatal error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer' not found in /xhome/rekha/public_html/PHP_FORUM/PHP/open_office/spread.php on line 4
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0003  59868   {main}( )   ../spread.php:0
```

I tried to solve this error.But I can't.
Please can anyone help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'll have to include the library, otherwise PHP won't recognize the Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer class.

And you'll also have to specify a path for the include_path, instead of a file.
And usually it's best practice to append your new path, to the existing path. So you'll first have to retrieve the current include_path and append your new path to that one.

This should work:

```
<?php
ini_set('include_path',ini_get('include_path').':/xhome/rekha/public_html/PHP_FORUM/PHP/open_office/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.2/');

require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';

$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
$workbook->send('grades.xls');
$format_bold =& $workbook->addFormat();

$format_bold->setBold();

$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet();

$worksheet->write(0, 0, "NAME", $format_bold);
$worksheet->write(0, 1, "MARK1", $format_bold);
$worksheet->write(0, 2, "MARK2", $format_bold);
$worksheet->write(0, 3, "MARK3", $format_bold);
$worksheet->write(0, 4, "MARK4", $format_bold);
$worksheet->write(0, 5, "MARK5", $format_bold);
$worksheet->write(0, 6, "TOTAL", $format_bold);

$workbook->close();
?>
```

And it seems that you've downloaded the source of the Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer and installed it manually in your project.

I suggest you use the PEAR installer, included with PHP to install this package. The PEAR libraries are usually included by default through he default include_path. So you should only need the 'require_once' statement. no need to change the include_path.

just enter on the command line:

```
pear install Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-beta
```

Once you've installed the library successfully using PEAR, you can remove the ini_set line from your script.

Hope this solves your problem.

Further informations regarding PEAR:
http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.cli.php

Answer (score 2):

I've used this library before but a better one is [PHPExcel](http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel) which supports more recent XLS and XSLX file formats.